# Ruby-on-rails development and production on same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible (or normal) to have Ruby on Rails development and production on the same server? And is it OK to have sqlite for development and postgresql for production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not normal, but it is possible - and occasionally needed - to debug problems that are only showing up in production.  A couple of examples are assets (javascripts, images, etc) that are served up differently in development as opposed to production due to the asset pipeline.  Another area is caching which tends to be different in production and is frequently disabled in development.

In ruby on rails there are usually (at least) three modes that the server can run in.
These are referred to as 'environments'.

- development.  This is your local machine and is what you normally use locally during development
- tests.  This is used when you run tests and test suites.
- production.  This is the mode used for actual production servers which are usually on a remote server.

Sometimes you do want/need to run a local development server in 'production mode' and in these cases you do this inline with

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails server
```

or

```
rails server -e production
```

or

```
rails server -e production -p 3001 
# Specify the port (e.g. **-p 3001**) if you want to run on a different port (the default port is 3000),
# e.g. to run in development mode in one window and production mode in another.
```

When you run your local server in another mode, such as production, you'll need to be aware that this also affects your database connection.  `config/database.yml` has your database connection and *also* uses the `RAILS_ENV` settings.
You may want/need to run your server in production mode - but use your local database.  You can do this by temporarily using the actual setting from the development block in the production block of `config/database.yml`.  Just be sure to save the original settings / restore afterwards (before you do your next push).

It's also totally ok and indeed common to have sqlite locally and mysql/postgres/oracle in production.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say it is "normal" or not to have both environments on a single server. A lot of small structures already do it, so to my mind it won't cause any problems.

Anyway, as long as both environments are clearly isolated (i.e. two separate folders at least, and two rvm gemsets or rbenv environments for the ruby and gem versions), it won't cause any problems. Just remember to launch both servers with different ports or sockets and you're done.

That is the way I've done for five projects and it ran without trouble.

Comment: did you tie them to the same database or a different database?

Comment: @napkinsterror I usually tie them to different databases, i.e. `<myapp>_dev` for the development environment and `<myapp>_<unspeakable_hash_of_doom>` for the production environment. In addition, I run both app servers with different users.

Answer (score 1):

You can run same app on same machine on different mode like `production` or `development` using different `port`

```
rails s  # which will run on development mode like localhost:3000
rails s -e production 3002  # for production mode like localhost:3002
```

second answer regarding database.. Yes you can use different database in different mode like for development `sqlite3` and for production `postgress` by modifying your `database.yml` file

```
    development:
      adapter: sqlite3
      database: yourapp_development
      username: root
      password: root
      host: localhost

   production:
      adapter: postgresql
      host: localhost
      username: postgres
      password: password
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000
      database: yourapp_production
```

and in your **gemfile**

```
group :development do
  gem "sqlite3"
end
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally run RoR in development mode *on development machines* - i.e., on your local system where application development takes place. The point is to run RoR in development-friendly manner - exposing error messages, avoiding the need to precompile assets, etc - it's slower but much easier to actively work with.

Having different database systems for development and production is possible, but inadvisable. Ideally the application development environment is closely matched with the production environment - allowing for your code to work in an identical, and predictable manner. SQLite3 can behave quite differently from PostgreSQL - the two have different feature-sets. There are a lot of things that PostgreSQL can do that SQLite can't (I'm not sure about the reverse). See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html for PostgreSQL-specific features.